# How to map frame extracted with ffmpeg and subtitle of a video? (frame accuracy problem)

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, frame-rate, subtitle

would like to generate text files for frames extracted with ffmpeg, containing subtitle of the frame if any, on a video for which I have burn the subtitles using ffmpeg also.

I use a python script with `pysrt` to open the subrip file and generate the text files.
What I am doing is that each frames is named with the frame number by ffmpeg, then and since they are extracted at a constant rate, I can easily retrieve the time position of the frame using the formula `t1 = fnum/fps`, where `fnum` is the number of the frame retrieved with the filename, and `fps` is the frequency passed to ffmpeg for the frame extraction.

Even though I am using the same subtitle file to retrieve the text positions in the timeline, that the one that has been used in the video, I still get accuracy errors. Most I have some text files missing or some that shouldn't be present.

Because time is not really continuous when talking about frames, I have tried recalibrating `t` using the fps of the video wih the hardcoded subtitles, let's call that fps `vfps` for video fps (I have ensured that the video fps is the same before and after subtitle burning). I get the formula: `t2 = int(t1*vfps)/vfps`.
It still is not 100% accurate.

For example, my video is at 30fps (`vfps=30`) and I extracted frames at 4fps (`fps=4`).
The extracted frame 166 (`fnum=166`) shows no subtitle. In the subrip file, the previous subtitle ends at `t_prev=41.330` and the next subtitle begins at `t_next=41.400`, which means that `t_sub` should satisfy: `t_prev < t_sub and t_sub < t_next`, but I can't make this happen.

Formulas I have tried:

```
t1 = fnum/fps  # 41.5 > t_next
t2 = int(fnum*vfps/fps)/vfps  # 41.5 > t_next
# is it because of a indexing problem? No:
t3 = (fnum-1)/fps  # 41.25 < t_prev
t4 = int((fnum-1)*vfps/fps)/vfps  # 41.23333333 < t_prev
t5 = int(fnum*vfps/fps - 1)/vfps  # 41.466666 > t_next
t6 = int((fnum-1)*vfps/fps + 1)/vfps  # 41.26666 < t_prev
```

Command used:

```sh
# burning subtitles
# (previously)
# ffmpeg -r 25 -i nosub.mp4 -vf subtitles=sub.srt withsub.mp4
# now:
ffmpeg -i nosub.mp4 -vf subtitles=sub.srt withsub.mp4
# frames extraction
ffmpeg -i withsub.mp4 -vf fps=4 extracted/%05.bmp -hide_banner
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve this?

One thing I have noticed is that if I extract frames of the original video and the subtitle ones, do a difference of the frames, the result is not only the subtitles, there are variations in the background (that shouldn't happen). If I do the same experience using the same video two times, the difference is null, which means that the frame extraction is consistant.

Code for the difference:

```sh
ffmpeg -i withsub.mp4 -vf fps=4 extracted/%05.bmp -hide_banner
ffmpeg -i no_sub.mp4 -vf fps=4 extracted_no_sub/%05.bmp -hide_banner
for img in no_sub/*.bmp; do
    convert extracted/${img##*/} $img -compose minus -composite diff/${img##*/}
done
```

Thanks.

Comment: *ffmpeg -r 25 -i nosub.mp4* --> this will retime frames and destroy original timestamps. You don't want to do this unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Not really... I wanted to burn the subtitles without changing the framerate. So I tried this first: `ffmpeg -i nosub.mp4 -vf subtitles=sub.srt withsub.mp4` but it changed the rate from 25 to 30, so I manually set the frame rate and it seems that it's not the right to do it. I am not a big user of ffmpeg. I googled for how to preserve framerate with ffmpeg and found this https://superuser.com/questions/460332/how-do-set-output-framerate-same-as-source-in-ffmpeg but it has no accepted answer.

Comment: Share the log of your original attempt.

Comment: My bad, the original fps was 30 so my first attempt to burn the subtitles did not change the frame rate. The problems remain however. And doing a frame substraction before and after subtitle burning shows more differences than the subtitle. Please let me remind that this is not the problem I am trying to solve, but may be the cause of my problem.
What log would you like to see?

Comment: It's also worth noticing that, in the example, the boundaries of the interval multiplied mulitplied by the frame extraction gives: `t_prev*fps=165.32` and `t_next*fps=165.6`, which implies that, if the frame extracted by ffmpeg are factors of `1/fps` then I shouldn't get frame 166 to be inbetween the two subtitles but displaying the second one instead (or the previous maybe). Same thing if correcting by the video fps: `int(t_next*vfps)*fps/vfps=165.2`, `int(t_next*vfps)*fps/vfps=165.6`

Comment: I've opened a question for the problem of the non-null difference of the frames before and after subtitle burning https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551928/ffmpeg-frames-extracted-after-subtitle-burning-differs-from-original

Comment: If you want the accurate timestamps of extracted frames, that can be done.

Comment: That could be a solution yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract frames with accurate timestamps, thus

```
ffmpeg -i nosub.mp4 -vf subtitles=sub.srt,settb=AVTB,select='if(eq(n\,0)\,1\,floor(4*t)-floor(4*prev_t))' -vsync 0 -r 1000 -frame_pts true extracted/%08d.bmp
```

This will extract the first frame from each quarter second. The output filename is 8 characters long where the first 5 digits are seconds and last three are milliseconds. You can change the field size based on max file duration.

Comment: Could you give a bit more details about the parameters please? Also I get an error: `Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(eq(n,0)'`

Comment: settb filter is used to set the timebase to 1 microsecond, The select filter expression will select the first frame and then select each frame nearest to the previous quarter second. -r 1000 will convert timestamps to millisecond accuracy (otherwise filename would get even longer). vsync ensures ffmpeg does not shift timestamps. frame_pts prints the timestamp into the filename.

Comment: Edited cmd to escape all commas